# Float your boat on lava?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was reading a post about the fastest way of traveling. Someone suggested traveling by minecart through the Nether, as this was a 8:1 ratio or something. Now I thought what if you encounter a lava lake? Building a bridge over there just to lay some tracks down seems like an awful amount of work. So here comes my question: are you able to simply catch a boat and sail across the lava lake?

Comment: Rail through the nether is most concerned with repeat trips.  Building a bridge is worth the time in the long run.  Additionally, if you're building a network, you usually do it in the ceiling, where it's mostly solid netherrack.

Comment: @MBraedley - or you build yourself a nice tunnel

Comment: @Robotnik: Yes, that was the implication of building it in the ceiling.

Comment: What I'm saying is you don't need a ceiling to make a tunnel. Cobblestone works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boat float on lava? **Yes**

Sail the boat? **No**

> The player may place boats in lava, but if they try to ride the boat
> it will break and they will fall into the lava.
>
> [A video of a boat placed on lava](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGLeidjf6fc)
>
> Using a Splash Potion of Fire Resistance can cause boats to be immune to fire.
> When riding a boat through lava without it dying, it will attach to the nearest block and will not be ridden like a boat on water.

**Edit:**

> "(...)if you use a fishing rod to pull yourself forward then?" – Marco
> Geertsma

It doesn't work, the boat doesn't move if you use it, and it doesn't move on water with that technique either. And it would be annoying fishing with that.

Comment: Come to think of it - I never tried to place a boat on lava (because wood + lave = burn).

Comment: @5pike yes that has been my assumption as well.

Comment: "When riding a boat through lava without it dying, it will attach to the nearest block and will not be ridden like a boat on water." What if you use a fishing rod to pull yourself forward then?

Comment: Oh man, now I have to go back to minecraft and try...

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not. This is completely illogical... You can place the boats into lava but if you try and use it, you will fall into the lava and die horribly.

Read this for more information:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Boat

Comment: While this is illogical, minecraft is not really logical either xD

Comment: Pfft.. Minecraft is completely logical ;) . But a WOODEN boat in LAVA (that molten rock stuff that is really hot)... come on...

Answer (score -2):

You cant go ride a boat on lava because think about it. If you put a boat in side lava it would float but getting inside the boat would make it sink and you will sink with it and die.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers. It's generally only worth adding a new answer if you have something more to add, or you disagree with the existing answers.